# Area under a basketball shot

Tags: integration, area, applications

The other day, someone asked me how to find the area under a basketball shot. It looked something like this:

[image]

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I think you need to supply more context.  Simple models of projectile motion (constant acceleration due to gravity, no air resistance) just yield a parabola which you could then integrate.  More complex models give rise to more complex trajectories.

Comment: @lulu it isn't a parabola, but what I want to know is how to go about the process: I understand that I'd first have to express the curve as an equation, and then integrate it, but any ideas on how I could do that?

Comment: A silly question : why is it formulated in feets instead of meters ?

Comment: As I say, it strongly depends on your model.  If you add air resistance and such your differential equation will quickly become non-integrable.  That's not a problem!  You don't need a functional form, you just need enough numerical values to do a Riemann Sums estimate.  But you need to write down the ODE you want.

Comment: Ignoring minor things (air resistance, the earth is not flat, etc.) the curve is a parabola.

Comment: To elaborate (slightly):  if you have an explicit ODE, then Euler's method (or whatever your favorite numerical method is) will give you points on the curve at whatever desired step size you choose.  You can then use those values and that step size to write out an approximation for the area (using Riemann Sums, or Simpson's rule, etc.)  Everything depends on the ODE.

Comment: @GEdgar  Is it?  Pop-ups in baseball absolutely aren't.  the spin on the ball makes for a very observable effect.  My guess would be that you are right about basketballs...are you sure though?

Comment: @lulu ... Interesting.  Well, the spin on a baseball has no effect without the air there, right?  And I said "ignoring air resistance".

Comment: @GEdgar  Oh, agreed.  But somebody out there must have filmed a basketball and checked...though I couldn't find an online reference (after 10 seconds of searching).  the pop-up effect is quite strong...the ball drops much closer in than it "should".  that's why infielders often have to scramble at the last second.

Comment: @GEdgar  Ok, [here's](http://www.phys.ubbcluj.ro/~emil.vinteler/infoaplicata/3%20Balistica%20externa/Baschet.pdf) someone who claims that, for basketballs, spin and air resistance generally don't have significant impact. Phew.

Comment: ... and since the earth is not flat, you have not a parabola but an ellipse ... assuming your throw is slower than escape velocity ...

Answer (score 1):

This is also related to physics, and we will ignore minor forces like air friction/drag and other trivial things.

Assumptions: $g$ is the constant of acceleration due to gravity and does not change, aside from the initial force of the ball being thrown and gravity, there are no additional forces, we will consider the ball to be a point-mass object (maybe some others I have forgotten).

The trajectory of the ball is given as:

$$\Delta y=V_{0y}t-gt^2\tag{Galileo's formula}$$

Since gravity does not affect the $x$ direction, and we assume $x_0=0$,

$$x=V_{0x}t$$

$$\implies t=\frac x{V_{0x}}$$

$$\implies\Delta y=V_{0y}\frac x{V_{0x}}-g\frac{x^2}{V_{0x}^2}$$

> $$y=V_{0y}\frac x{V_{0x}}-g\frac{x^2}{V_{0x}^2}+y_0$$

The area is simply given as

$$\int_0^dydx=\int_0^dV_{0y}\frac x{V_{0x}}-g\frac{x^2}{V_{0x}^2}+y_0dx$$

$$=V_{0y}\frac d{2V_{0x}}-g\frac{d^3}{3V_{0x}^2}+y_0d$$

where we use metric units and $V_0$ represent the initial velocity in a direction, $g=9.81m/s^2$, $y_0$ is the initial height, and $d$ is the $x$ distance to the hoop.

Comment: In the iPhone app, the tag "Galileo's formula" obscures half of the equation, even in the rotated view. In every other respect, this seems a complete and accurate answer.